# Visual Studio adornment extension events not being fired

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a basic adornment function for my visual studio plugin. i already have a tool window and some commands set up, and i am in the process of trying to get adronment to work.

Following this [walk through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818135.aspx) from Microsoft, i was under the impression that adding the creation listener class to my project and setting it up as is in the walk though; visual studio would automatically load that part of my plugin and create the listener for me. The event which i am listening for never seems to be fired however.

Below is the main snippet of the code i am using.

```
[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("code")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.PrimaryDocument)]
internal sealed class Flare_Client_AdornmentFactory : IWpfTextViewCreationListener {


    public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView) {
        new Flare_Client_Adornment(textView);
    }
}
```

I think that i may be missing a step and i have to register somewhere that this exists, but i do not know where to look. What do i have to do to get this event registered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked out what the issue was. As i was adding adornment to an existing VsPackage project, i needed to set another Asset in my vsixmanifest to allow my project to also be an MefComponent (which is the project type for adornment).

Below is a screenshot of my vsixmanifest to help show my solution better.

[image]